# Opening UIPickerView instead of Keyboard on TextView clicked

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uipickerview

I have seen examples on SO where people set their Picker Views' state to hidden = false / true, as the views are set up in the storyboard.

Is there anyway to replace the keyboard with the picker view, so I can use the same functions and treat the picker view the same way as I would a keyboard.

i.e - shift views when keyboard appears etc.

I will also need the option to say I have chosen an option. So instead of a "Done Editing" button, I just click outside the picker view, which I know how to do with a keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

> if you want to picker view for text fields instead of keyboard

```
textField.inputView = PickerView;
```

- don't want done button then handle the touch events.
- touch begin event handle the keyboard pickerView hide.
- other wise change parentView class from **UIView** to **UIControl** ,
    and take Action handle in the action method.